# Generating report in Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to generate a **report**(i.e pdf or any format that can be print) from the data in system. Its like i need to generate weekly report. Format of report will be the same but data will be change with time. Is there any way to perform this task in **Node JS** ? I m using Mongo DB. And **React JS** in front end. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ZeeshanHassanMemon. Exactly what i m looking for. Perfect

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use this npm package to convert your data into pdf format. Just by giving id of the tag that contains your data.

You can download it in pdf format. and print it as well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) as it is a big library having more than 18k github star. if you want to make report from frontend only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the HTML based pdf then [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) lib. It is the best lib to convert your HTML to pdf. I have already use the lib in my many projects to generate the pdf reports.